# Complex Synthetic Data - Create manually or use a package/tool?

Tags: r, data-science

The data I work with consists of multiple tables (around 5-10) with single tables containing up to 10 million entries. So, overall I'd describe it as a large data set, but not too large to work with on a 'normal' computer. I'm in the need of a synthetic data set with the same structure and internal dependencies, i.e. a dummy data set. I can't use the data I work with as the data contains sensitive information.

I did research on synthetic data and came across different solutions. The first would be online providers where one uploads the original data and synthetic data is created based on the given input. This sounds like a nice solution, but I'd rather not share the original data with any external sources, so this is currently not an option for me.

The second solution I came across isthe *synthpop* package in R. I tried that, however, I encountered two problems: the first one being that for larger tables (as the tables in the orginal data sets are) it takes a very long time to execute. The second one being that I only got it working for a single table, however, I need to keep the dependencies between the tables, otherwhise the synthetic data doesn't make any sense.

The third option would be to do the whole data creation by myself. I have good and solid knowledge about the domain and the data, so I would be able to define the internal constraints formally and then write a script to follow these. The problem I see here is that it would obviously be a lot of work and as I'm no expert on synthetic data creation, I might still overlook something important.

So basically I have two questions:

1. Is there a good package/solution you can recommend (preferably in R, but ultimately the programming language doesn't matter so much) for automatically creating synthetic (and private) data based on original input data consisting of multiple tables?
2. Would you recommend the manual approach or would you recommend to spend more time on the *synthpop* package for example and try that approach?

Comment: Even though it's a good question, I'm afraid it is off-topic here. Stack Overflow acts as a repository of answers to _specific_ programming questions. There are not enough details about what specifically you are trying to achieve to allow a concrete answer with a worked example, and any answers it does attract are going to be opinion based. I have therefore voted to close this question as opinion-based. For what it's worth, if it were me, I would probably attempt to generate the data from scratch, but that's only because I would enjoy the challenge :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'm sorry about that! Would this question be appropiate for datascience.stackexchange?